# How to match all alphabet except few?

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match `[a-z]` only except the letters `a,e,i,o,u`

Using negated set `[^aeiou]*` I could match everything except `a,e,i,o,u`, but how to restrict my `everything` to `[a-z]`?

This can be easily done using character class subtraction (`[a-z-[aeiou]]`)  in XML Schema, XPath, .NET (2.0+), and JGsoft regex flavors, but how can I do it in PCRE?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead assertion. It's like a kind of subtraction.

```
(?![aeiou])[a-z]
     ^        ^
     |        |
subtract    from
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aA6eK0/1)

Comment: Perfect!.. is it possible to capture the matches in groups? i tried `(?![aeiou])([a-z])+?` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aA6eK0/3).. matches are individual letters..

Comment: You'd need to wrap the parens around the whole RE: `((?![aeiou])[a-z])` for one, or `((?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])+)` for many (one or more), I think.  You might get away with just a + after the first RE I suggest.

Comment: @hwnd alphabet that are not `a,e,i,o,u`.. Ex.. in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aA6eK0/3).. `bcd`, `fghjklmnpqrst`, `vwxyz`

Comment: This could be written as `((?:(?![eiou])[b-z])+)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this with the wildcard search in Microsoft Word. But Word does not accept this syntax for excluding i from all small caps letters: (?![i])[a-z]. Thanks for ideas!