# regex: How to match the set of a language's characters, with some exceptions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Let me use the set of English characters as an example, though the question is really about how to make this work in general for any language's set of characters.

I want to write a regex that matches two characters from the set (a-zA-Z) EXCEPT for some specific letters. For the English language, lets say the exception list is : any of CIKMOV or their lowercase cikmov.

While I could write it as follows for the English set of characters:

```py
mo = re.search(r"[ABD-HJLNP-UW-Zabd-hjlnp-uw-z]{2}", s)
```

it is not compact and more importantly requires me to have knowledge of the set of characters in that language so that I can enumerate the subsets. but I have only been given the exception list for each language and am not knowledgeable on all the languages.

Ofcourse, the following doesnt work for me:

```py
mo = re.search(r"[^cikmovCIKMOV]{2}", s)
```

as it only excludes the exception list but includes everything else (including characters not in the language set).

Is there a better way to write the regex than the above tedious method of specifying the character subsets removing the exceptions ?

The language to choose comes as a dynamic input (and so is not restricted to English/en-us only) and the exceptions for each language are specified as follows:

```py
exceptionlist["en-us"] = "cikmovCIKMOV"
exceptionlist["de-de"] =
```

**Edit**: 
I dont think this is a duplicate of [how to match all alphabet except few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859968/how-to-match-all-alphabet-except-few). That question assumes I know the "a" and "z" of a language. But here all i have is the exception list of a language.

Comment: don't use regex; use if char.isalpha() together with not in exception_list; you will have to take care of providing correct encoding for this to work

Comment: You can exclude `cikmovCIKMOV` AND `\W` (small `'\w` means "word characters", big `\W` means "non-word characters")

Comment: According the Wiktor's duplicate this should work `re.search('(?:(?![cikmovCIKMOV])[a-zA-Z]){2}', s)`

Comment: @h4z3  Is this regex really restricting me to the set of characters of a _specific_ chosen language (one at a time) ?

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate of the question specified by Wiktor. That question assumes I know the "a" and "z" of a language. But here all i have is the exception list of a language.

Comment: I have prepared answer that works for you but can't post here anymore I will num lines: 1. exceptionlist_en = 'cikmovCIKMOV' 2. text = 'A0ch2evf23bM2345I6e' 3. for c in text: 4. if c.isalpha(): 5. if not c in exceptionlist_en: 6. print(c) 7. else: 8. continue

Comment: hope you will put correct indentations yourself and hope this solves as it does not require to know the full list

Comment: @Drako: But how is `isalpha()` going to help me with other languages ? If `text = 'München'` and I am dealing with Japanese I dont want to match the english or german language characters ?

Comment: did you try the 'München'? - isalpha() correctly gives true for all letters in this word - so it works for other langs too - haven't checked for hieroglyphs tho

Comment: from docs: str.isalpha()
Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise. Alphabetic characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Letter”, i.e., those with general category property being one of “Lm”, “Lt”, “Lu”, “Ll”, or “Lo”. Note that this is different from the “Alphabetic” property defined in the Unicode Standard.

Comment: obviously you can have issues with some weirdly defined langs that does not have proper category set for them in unicode cahr db but then only way is to have full list charset .

Comment: i'll provid my answer at the 'original' question provided by Wiktor

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it very easy to build? Like:

```
availablelist["en-us"] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
exceptionlist["en-us"] = "cikmovCIKMOV"

regexes["en-us"] = re.compile(f"[{"".join([char in availablelist["en-us"] if char not in exceptionlist["en-us"]])}]")
```

You can pre-compile every regex you need.

Comment: as stated in Question - availablelist is not known to author

Comment: @Drako This is not even a problem. Why not just Google it. And I don't really think there could be a way to specify a subset without knowing the superset.

Comment: why not just use pythons built-in isalpha()?

Comment: @Drako Well, the reason is that I think it won't really cover what OP needs. Let's say if he/she needs Japanese?

Comment: actually just tested it works correctly with Japanese as well :)